# SWIG-wrapped objects in Tcl; destructors not being called on exit

Tags: tcl, swig

I have the following scenario:

SWIG-wrapped class `A` (contains a std::thread which is joined on destruction, and which is running its own Tcl interpreter)
Tcl interpreter prompt `%`

```
% A a
% a -delete
% exit
```

The above works just fine. GDB reports that the thread spawned by `A a`, owned by object `a`, is stopped.

```
% A a
% exit
```

The above results in the destructor of the underlying C++ class not being called, the thread continuing to run, and havoc to break loose on program exit (in the still running thread, which is quite unprepared for its sudden loss of its existence). This is fine and dandy, because it's program exit, but it doesn't leave me any less quizzical about *why* the destructor isn't being called.

Is there some sort of setting in SWIG that I can use to tell it to clean up after itself?

(deliberately not tagged with C++, because this question really isn't about C++...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl does not delete memory structures when it responds to an `exit` because that is usually a total waste of time. Finalization is expensive, and the OS is typically far better at it than applications.

But there are exceptions. You've got one of them. What you need to do is install an exit handler with  [`Tcl_CreateExitHandler`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/Exit.htm) that closes down the thread despite the object still existing. I don't know how to integrate this with SWIG.

The other approach is to put your code in a sub-interpreter (see the `interp` command) and make `exit` just quit that sub-interpreter. Then the commands *will* be deleted neatly (and the master interpreter can just cleanly go away once it sees the child finish).

Comment: Welp, I don't think I'm getting a better answer than this one.